# Is there a way using templates to avoid narrowing conversion?

Tags: c++, templates

Using the following as example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>struct X
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    void clear() { v.clear(); }
    ~X(){}
    X(){ clear(); }
    X(const X &x) { v=x.v; }
    //template<typename ...I> X(I...i) : v({static_cast<T>(i)...}) {} //<---gets rid of warnings only, still narrowing
    template<typename ...I> X(I...i) : v({i...}) {}
    template<typename U> X(const U &u) { for (auto e:u.v) v.push_back((T)e); }

    bool operator==(const X &x) const { return (v==x.v); }
    template<typename U> bool operator==(const U &u) { X<T> x(u); return (v==x.v); }

    void show(const std::string &s) const
    {
        using TYPE=typename std::common_type<T,int>::type;
        std::cout << s << " = ";
        for (auto x:v) std::cout << (TYPE)x << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
};

template<typename T> bool testit(const T a, const T b)
{
    return (a==b);
}

template<typename T> bool testit(const X<T> a, const X<T> b)
{
    return (a==b);
}

template<typename T, typename U> bool testit(const X<T> a, const X<U> b)
{
    X<T> c(b); // this is the problem - t=int, U=double => narrowing
    return testit(a, c);

/*
    // tried doesn't work

    if (sizeof(decltype(T()))<sizeof(decltype(U())))
    {
        X<U> c(a);
        X<U> d(b);
        return testit(c,d);
    }
    else
    {
        X<T> c(a);
        X<T> d(b);
        return testit(c,d);
    }
*/

/*
    //doing the following causes a segfault -- I have no idea why

    using T1=typename std::common_type<T, int>::type;
    using T2=typename std::common_type<U, int>::type;
    using TT=typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type;
    X<TT> c(a);
    X<TT> d(b);
    return testit(d,b);
*/

}


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    auto res=[](bool b)->std::string{ return b?"OK":"Fail"; };
    auto test=[res](const std::string s, bool btest, bool bexp){ std::cout << s << " - " << res(btest==bexp) << "\n"; };

    test("(1,1)", testit(1,1), 1);
    test("(1,2)", testit(1,2), 0);
    test("(abc,abc)", testit("abc","abc"), 1);
    test("(abc,aaa)", testit("abc","aaa"), 0);

    X<int> xa{1,2,3};               xa.show("xa");
    X<double> xb{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};    xb.show("xb");
    X<char> xc{2,4,6};              xc.show("xc");
    X<double> xd{1.1, 2.1, 3.1};    xd.show("xd");


    test("(xa, xb)", testit(xa,xb), 1);
    test("(xa, xc)", testit(xa,xc), 0);
    test("(xb, xc)", testit(xb,xc), 0);

    test("(xc, {2.0, 4.0, 6.0})", testit(xc, {2.0, 4.0, 6.0}), 1);
    test("(xc, {2.0, 4.1, 6.0})", testit(xc, {2.0, 4.1, 6.0}), 0);

    test("(X<int>({4, 5, 6}), {4.0, 5.0, 6.0})", testit(X<int>({4, 5, 6}), {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}), 1);
    test("(X<int>({4, 5, 6}), {4.0, 5.0, 6.1})", testit(X<int>({4, 5, 6}), {4.0, 5.0, 6.1}), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

which cause narrowing when T is int and U is double.

Since I don't know in which order the template-arguments are at run-time, is there a way to avoid this narrowing - so that int is converted to double - no matter the order of the arguments?

Comment: @Jarod42: thx, fixed it up with a couple of lambdas

Answer (score 3):

Warnings come from the one constructor of `X` with variadic parameter pack. You silence the compiler by being explicit with a cast:

```
template<typename ...I> X(I...i) : v({static_cast<T>(i)...}) {}
```

This gets rid of the warning from, say, `X<char> xc{2,4,6};` where I assume you don't mind the narrowing.

The actualy avoid narrowing when constructing `X` inside `testit`, you can use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
X< std::common_type_t<T,U> > c(b);
```

Comment: Although it [segfaults](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80ead702056f1c05) when I use `common_type`, so it seems you've got other bugs in the code.

Comment: I am doing: `using TYPE=typename std::common_type<T,U>::type; X<TYPE> c(a); X<TYPE> d(b);`  no segfault, but still narrowing ... that is if I understand std::common_type correctly (by the way I use gcc/linux)

Comment: @slashmais Yeah, the segfault was my bad. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b793542cd933acd6), the warnings are gone. Another problem is overload resolution picking wrong `testit`, now...

Comment: yeah, see what you mean; at least I got some ideas to play with now, we'll solve this yet - by the way the static_cast just hides the warnings, does nothing else I can see

Comment: seems it fails to resolving brace-initializer from function-parameter - making it explicit X<type>{...} solves that. Wonder why it fails, the constructor is there...

Answer (score 1):

To silent the warning, do the cast explicitly:

```
template<typename ...I> X(I...i) : v({static_cast<T>(i)...}) {}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f35d6bafe4f9c2a0)

Comment: Gets rid of the warnings only, the narrowing still happen - anyway I want to see the warnings to know that the code is still doing wrong

Comment: `testit(xc, {2.0, 4.0, 6.0})` would use `bool testit(const X<char>&, const X<char>&)` as `{2.0, 4.0, 6.0}` has no type. Removing those calls and using `if consexpr` for the other method has no warnings [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc8989d9a9584705).